# sqlite use of both AND and IN operators

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to know how to select from a table where there are two "where" parameters and both are array strings. 
Here is my code for one parameter:

```
String[] wheres = new String[globalRunnersList.size()];

    String questionMarks = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < globalRunnersList.size(); i++)
    {
        wheres[i] = globalRunnersList.get(i).getAthleteId();
        questionMarks += ",?";
    }
    questionMarks = questionMarks.substring(1);

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "ActivityMeasurements", new String[] {"MeasurementAttemptId"},"Athlete IN ("+questionMarks+")", wheres, null, null, null, null);
    if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            measAttempts.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("MeasurementAttemptId")));
        }
        while(mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return measAttempts;
```

I would like to change query like this:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "ActivityMeasurements", new String[] {"MeasurementAttemptId"},"Athlete IN ("+questionMarks+") AND ActivityDefinition IN("+anotherQuestionMarks+")", wheres, null, null, null, null);
```

"anotherQuestionMarks" will be calculated from another wheres string, but how can i pass another string in "selectionArgs"?

Can this be done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "anotherQuestionMarks" will be calculated from another wheres string, but how can i pass another string in "selectionArgs"?

`selectionArgs` (or `wheres` in your code) is just an array and the values there will be used to bind values for each `?` placeholder in the query string, from left to right. So just add your additional values to the `selectionArgs` array. Remember to allocate enough space for both sets of values.

Comment: ok, this sounds very logical and it works perfectly, thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another **selectionArgs** as suggested by @laalto as follows.

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "ActivityMeasurements", new String[] {"MeasurementAttemptId"},"Athlete IN (?) AND ActivityDefinition IN(?)",new String[]{ wheres ,mActivityDefinitionArray}, null, null, null, null);
```

or another approach is to use **db.rawQuery** for creating query with sql syntex as any other database systems.

Comment: You cannot use `?` for a comma-separated list of values. You need to have a `?` for each value as the OP is already doing.

Comment: ok. thanx @laalto for explaining. That cleared my concept also. but he could also use rawquery. is it right ?

Comment: Yes, `rawQuery()` is always possible and the same deal with `?` and selection args array applies there, too. `query()` is just a fancy string builder for `rawQuery()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i read the question correctly but:

Why don't use CriteriaQuery, something like

```
//cb = CriteriaBuilder
CriteriaQuery q = cb.createQuery(class);
 query.where(
  cb.and(
      cb.in(c.between("Athlete"), questionMarks),
      cb.in(c.between("ActivityDefinition"), anotherQuestionMarks)
  )
);
```

or

```
createCriteria(class)
    .add( Restrictions.in("Athlete", questionMarks) )
    .add( Restrictions.in("ActivityDefinition", anotherQuestionMarks) )
```